# Telnet input communicate through HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, telnet

For the following code how would I have the textbox filled by input coming from a outside source or in my case I would like the textbox to be filled remotely through telnet. How I might accomplish this. Thanks!

Javascript:

```
 function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      var t1 = document.getElementById("text1");
      var t2 = document.getElementById("text");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
      if(x.trim().toLowerCase() == 'mute'){
        t1.style.color = 'green';
        t2.style.color = 'green';
      }
      else if(x.trim().toLowerCase() == 'muteon'){
        t1.style.color = 'red';
        t2.style.color = 'red';
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>
<h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-10">
  <p id="text1" style="color:white; font-weight: 600">Text 1</p>
</h1>

<h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-60">
  <p id="text" style="color:crimson; font-weight: 600">Text</p>
</h1>
```